# How to decode unwell-formed hex string of emoji character like "`1f1e81f1f3`"?

Tags: java, unicode, decode, emoji

Suppose there's a hex string of emoji character like "`1f1e81f1f3`", it's unwell-formed hex string of code point of an emoji character, and it's supposed to be two string like `1f1e8` `1f1f3`

I'm using [`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) to decode hex string, but obviously Hex need the length of input string be even, so I need to make the hex string in zero padding style like "**0**`1f1e8`**0**`1f1f3`".

Currently, I simply replace "1f" with "01f", so far so good, but since [an emoji glyph may contains a sequence of unicode characters](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-zwj-sequences.html), so

- Is it safe to simply replace "1f" with "01f" ?
- If it's not safe, how to decode such hex string safely/properly and restore/translate them to correct emoji character/character_sequence? It seems I need to implement a custom UTF16BE decoder?

### Background

This hex string of emoji character is stripped from "`<span class="emoji emojiXXXXXXXXXX"></span>`" string, it's a text message retrieved from a popular IM software via unofficial HTTP API.

Comment: uh, obviously it's not safe, it's not even safe for the sample hex string in title, `1f1f3` becomes `01f01f3`.

Comment: The only safe way is to look up the definition of the `emojiXXXXXXXXXX` class in the corresponding style sheet.

Comment: `<span class="emoji emoji1f1e8"></span><span class="emoji emoji1f1f3"></span>` origin? Then, you can get a well-formed hex string(s) instead of _ill-formed_ one.

Comment: @JosefZ, no, they are not separated, one emoji glyph use only one `<span>` instead, all the character sequence of an emoji glyph is represented in hex string inside the `class` attribute of `span` element. I use the following regular expression to extract the hex string: `<span class=\"emoji emoji(\\p{XDigit}+)\"></span>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ends up with writing a small function to restore emoji characters.

Basic procedure:

1. Make a pointer to the start of the hex string.
2. Search from the the pointer position of the hex string,

   - If it's starts with "`1f`", then pad three zeroes before "`1f`", store it to a new hex string, then pointer step to next 5th position. Otherwise, no zero padding is made, store the sub string to a new hex string, and pointer step to the next 4th position.
   - Decode the new hex string to byte array.
   - Create new String using UTF_32BE or UTF_16BE character encoding from the byte array.
3. Loop to step 2, until end of the hex string.

**It works, but it's not perfect, it could introduce bug if**

- One character of emoji character sequence is located in supplementary character
- And
- It's hex string does not starts with "`1f`", or the length of it's hex string is not 5.

Code snippet:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

public static final Charset UTF_32BE = Charset.forName ("UTF-32BE");
public static final String REGEXP_FindTransformedEmojiHexString = "<span class=\"emoji emoji(\\p{XDigit}+)\"></span>";
public static final Pattern PATTERN_FindTransformedEmojiHexString = Pattern.compile (REGEXP_FindTransformedEmojiHexString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
public static String RestoreEmojiCharacters (String sContent)
{
        bMatched = true;
        String sEmojiHexString = matcher.group(1);

        Hex hex = new Hex (StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        try
        {
            for (int i=0; i<sEmojiHexString.length ();)
            {
                String sEmoji = null;
                Charset charset = null;
                String sSingleEmojiGlyphHexString = null;
                String sStartString = StringUtils.substring (sEmojiHexString, i, i+2);
                if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase (sStartString, "1f"))
                {
                    sSingleEmojiGlyphHexString = "000" + StringUtils.substring (sEmojiHexString, i, i+5);
                    i += 5;
                    charset = UTF_32BE;
                }
                else
                {
                    sSingleEmojiGlyphHexString = StringUtils.substring (sEmojiHexString, i, i+4);
                    i += 4;
                    charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE;
                }
                byte[] arrayEmoji = null;
                arrayEmoji = (byte[])hex.decode (sSingleEmojiGlyphHexString);
                sEmoji = new String (arrayEmoji, charset);
                matcher.appendReplacement (sbReplace, sEmoji);
            }
        }
        catch (DecoderException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    matcher.appendTail (sbReplace);

    if (bMatched)
        sContent = sbReplace.toString ();

    return sContent;
}
```